# What is "Phrase structure grammar"?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, formal-grammars, computation-models

I'm undertaking Theory of Computation Classes. I came across this sentence while studying Recursively Enumerable Grammar:

> Type-0 grammars generate recursively enumerable languages. The
>   productions have no restrictions. They are any phrase structure grammar
>   including all formal grammars.

What is difference between Formal Grammar and Phrase Structure Grammar?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_structure_grammar

Comment: In addition to @Yuval having corrected the posted quote from "Phase" to "Phrase Structure Grammar," I'll also recommend reading up on the Chomsky hierarchy for a big picture view.

Comment: Sure. I'll surely give it a read.